# How to use or what is the alternative for notification builder in Android ice cream version?

Tags: android

Do this code runs in ice cream version of Android?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `NotificationCompat` should work back to API Level 4.